# Communication between two nodes running Java apps using SSH tunnel

Tags: java, ssh, tunnel

I'm running an application on a bunch of nodes in a class A network, but can only access them from my own system if I log into the only node in that network that also has a class B address.

However, the client portion (with the GUI and everything) can run only on my system, so I need some way of communicating with the class A network. The client (my system) attempts to set up a simple TCP socket to the server (at the edge of the internal network, with a ServerSocket), but gets a Connection Timed Out exception. Since only the SSH port 22 is open, someone recommended I use SSH tunneling to send packets from my system to the internal network.

After a bit of Googling, I see that the following allows you to set up an SSH tunnel, but how would I use this from within Java to set up the sockets and what not? Thanks!

```
ssh -L 2222:10.10.10.10:22 174.174.174.174
```

**EDIT:**
I have used JSch to set up port forwarding from my system to an internal node, but is there any way I can make it bidirectional without having to set up a separate tunnel on every internal node? (The nodes aren't using the same TCP connection to respond, but have set up new connections to my laptop's port 2222.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to programatically set up the forwarded ports, use [JSch which supports port forwarding](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingL.java).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need to do. I've put up an excerpt of the code I'm trying out to make the connection, but so far I'm still getting Connection Timed Out exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

SSL Tunnel works just like any other socket, you just need to connect to the local socket. In your case, it's,

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 2222);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
```

The tunnel will actually make a connection to 10.10.10.10:22.

Comment: I believe you mean "SSH", not "SSL" ;-).

Comment: @MattSolnit, ZZCoder means SSL. It is an SSL tunnel.